# Subscribing with Ably Not Working in Production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, vercel, ably-realtime

I shipped an application to production using Vercel and Ably. In short, on a button click, I publish an event to a channel from my react client. On my node backend, I am subscribed to that channel for that specific event. In my local setup, the event listener triggers perfectly, but in production, the event never runs. I've used the Ably dev console to publish the same event on that channel and that still doesn't work.I've used `log: { level: 4 }` to output verbose logs using Axiom and it seems that ably connects to the proper channel on the backend.

Here is the problem in more detail, with code snippets.

**FRONT END:**

- On the frontend, I click a button called "Find a match". This opens up the "FindingMatchDialog.js" (see code snippet). Within the dialog, 3 major steps happen

  - We attach to the channel, "all_users_matching_channel". All attaching on the frontend is done through the "useChannel.js" hook (see code snippet).
  - We attach to the channel, "match-finding-user-${user.user_id}". In this case, the user_id is 1, so the channel becomes, "match-finding-user-1".

    - Notice that it is on this channel that we listen to the event, "match_not_found".
  - A timer is set, so that after 3 seconds, we publish an event to the "all_users_matching_channel". This event is called, "match_request".

Note: The expected outcome is that ably will respond to the "match_not_found" event that is published on the "match-finding-user-1" channel from the backend. You can see that in "FindingMatchDialog.js", if ably were to respond to the "match_not_found" event, we would get a console.log of "listening to Match not found". The issue is that this never gets logged.

**BACK END:**

- On the backend, we define the "/token-request" API route that returns the ably instance for the frontend to use (see "routes/ably/index.js" code snippet).
- We have an "ably-service" file that runs an "initialize" function. This connects to ably.
- The initialize function also runs the function, "setUpAllUsersChannelSubscriptions". This function connects to the "all_users_matching_channel" channel (recall from the frontend). We set up the subscription on that channel for the event, "match_request". In that subscription handler, we run the function, "mockOnMatchRequest" function.

  - In the "mockOnMatchRequest", we retrieve the "match-finding-user-1" channel and publish the "match_not_found" event.

It is this "match_not_found" event that should then be listened to on the front end. So here is the issue:

**THE ISSUE:**

The "match_not_found" is never listened to on the frontend. It seems like the "mockOnMatchRequest" on the backend is not run at all. None of the logs are outputted.

It turns out that after the button press, no new backend logs appear. It's as if the "match_request" event is not being listened to on the backend. I've attached screenshots of the Ably dev console, where I've attached to the "all_users_matching_channel" and the "match-finding-user-1" channel. You'll notice that the "match_request" event does get published (as seen in the Ably dev console). However, the "match_not_found" never shows up on the Ably dev console. This makes me believe there is something wrong with the subscription to the "all_users_matching_channel" for the event, "match_request".

You have a copy of the JS code where I subscribe to the "all_users_matching_channel" on the backend, so please let me know if something is being done incorrectly there.

**MY HUNCHES:**

- I don't think that the backend is subscribing to the "all_users_matching_channel" properly for the event, "match_request". Because if it were, it would run the "mockOnMatchRequest" function and the frontend would listen to the "match_not_found" event that gets published.
- Sometimes, when I refresh my screen, then the "match_not_found" event gets triggered. It's as if these chain of events were stored somewhere, waiting for a refresh.  It's confusing. I'm not so sure why this happens.

I hope this abundance of information is not overwhelming. Please take a look at how I am connection to ably, publishing/subscribing to the events (especially on the backend). Hopefully, you can help me figure out what the issue is. Also, this is all working fine on my local environment, so that makes it a little tougher.

Thank you! And let me know if you need any more information or clarification.

Here are the code snippets:

## FindingMatchDialog.js

## **

```
...
import { useChannel } from '../../hooks/useChannel';
//
----------------------------------------------------------------

export default function FindingMatchDialog({ isOpen, onClose,
imgSrc, user, question }) {

const [allUsersMatchChannel, allUsersMatchChannelAbly] = useChannel({
   channelName: ALL_USERS_MATCHING_CHANNEL,
});

const [userChannel, userChannelAbly] = useChannel({ 
   channelName: `match-finding-user-${user.user_id}`,
   eventNames: [MATCH_FOUND, MATCH_NOT_FOUND],
   callbackOnMessageMap: {
      [MATCH_FOUND]: (message, _channel) => {
          const data = message.data;
          navigate(PATH_APP.conversations.view(data.match_id));
    },
     [MATCH_NOT_FOUND]: (message, _channel) => {
        console.log("listening to Match not found")
       openNoMatchDialog();
    }
},
});

useEffect(() => {
   const matchRequestTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Sending out match request!!")
      allUsersMatchChannel.publish(MATCH_REQUEST, {
          question_id: question.question_id,
          user_id: user.user_id,
 });
}, 3000);

return () => {
   clearTimeout(matchRequestTimer);
}
}, [])

...

}
```

## useChannel.js

## **

```
import Ably from "ably/promises";

export const ably = new Ably.Realtime.Promise({
   authUrl: `${API_URL}/ably/token-request`,
   log: { level: 4 }
});

export function useChannel({ channelName, eventNames, callbackOnMessageMap, handleUnmount, effectListenerProps = [] })
{
   const channel = ably.channels.get(channelName);
   
   const onMount = async () => {
      if (eventNames) {
         console.log("subscribing channelName: ", channelName)
         
        for (const eventName of eventNames) {
            channel.subscribe(eventName, (msg) => {
                callbackOnMessageMap[eventName](msg, channel);
        });
}
}
}

const onUnmount = () => {
   console.log("unsubscribing channelName: ", channelName)
   
   channel.unsubscribe();
   
   if (handleUnmount) {
       handleUnmount();
   }
}

const useEffectHook = () => {
    onMount();
    
    return () => { onUnmount(); };
};

useEffect(useEffectHook, [...effectListenerProps]);

return [channel, ably];
}
```

## ably-service/index.js

## **

```
...

class AblyService {

ably;

initialize = async (passedTrx = null) => {
   let trx;

    try {
        log.debug('ABLY INITIALIZE', { testData: 32423 })
        
        const realtime = new Ably.Realtime({
            key: process.env.VERCEL_ENV === "production" ? process.env.ABLY_API_KEY_PRODUCTION : 
            process.env.ABLY_API_KEY_DEVELOPMENT,
            log: { level: 4 },
      });

       this.ably = realtime;
       this.ably.connection.once("connected");
       console.log("NOW Connected to Ably!!");

      trx = await startTrx(Match, passedTrx);
      await this.setUpAllUsersChannelSubscriptions({});
 
      await commitTrx(trx, passedTrx);
} catch (err) {
    console.error({
       filename,
       function: "initialize",
       message: `Failed to initialize ably service: ${err}`,
    });

    await rollbackTrx(trx, err);
    throw err;
}
}

setUpAllUsersChannelSubscriptions = async ({ passedTrx = null }) => {
   let trx;

    try {
        trx = await startTrx(Match, passedTrx);

     // get the finding match channel
    const allUsersMatchChannel = this.ably.channels.get(ALL_USERS_MATCHING_CHANNEL);

    await allUsersMatchChannel.subscribe(MATCH_REQUEST, async (message) => {
       console.log("GOT MATCH REQUEST!!! message: ", message)

      const currentUserChannel = this.ably.channels.get(`user-${message.data.user_id}`);

      await this.mockOnMatchRequest({ 
          user_id: +message.data.user_id,
          question_id: +message.data.question_id, 
          currentUserChannel: currentUserChannel,
      });
})

    await commitTrx(trx, passedTrx);
} catch (err) {
    console.error({
       filename,
       function: "setUpAllUsersChannelSubscriptions",
       message: `Failed to set up finding match channel subscriptions: ${err}`
,
});
await rollbackTrx(trx, err);
throw err;
}
}

mockOnMatchRequest = async ({ user_id, question_id, currentUserChannel, passedTrx = null }) => {
   console.log('mockOnMatchRequest! SENDING MATCH NOT FOUND')

   const leftUserChannel = this.ably.channels.get(`match-finding-user-${user_id}`);

   await leftUserChannel.publish(MATCH_NOT_FOUND, {});
   }
}

const ablyService = new AblyService();
export default ablyService;
```

## routes/ably/index.js

## **

```
...

router.get("/token-request", async (_req, res) => {
   try {
      const client = new Ably.Realtime({
          key: process.env.VERCEL_ENV === "production" ?
          process.env.ABLY_API_KEY_PRODUCTION :
          process.env.ABLY_API_KEY_DEVELOPMENT,
          log: { level: 4 },
});

const tokenRequestData = await client.auth.createTokenRequest({ 
    clientId: process.env.VERCEL_ENV === "production" 
    ? process.env.ABLY_CLIENT_ID_PRODUCTION 
    : process.env.ABLY_CLIENT_ID_DEVELOPMENT });

return res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json(tokenRequestData);
} catch (err) {
   return res.status(StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send({ err: (err.message || err) });
 }
});

export default router;
```

[Ably Dev Console Screenshot - all_users_matching_channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw5K1.png)

[Ably Dev Console Screenshot - match-finding-user-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uB6L.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of questions.

1. What has changed from your development environment?

The only difference I can see is the clientId is different for development as for production, so I would double check that this is as expected. If your clientId become unaligned, you won't be sending your messages to the right channels, because your channel names are tied to your userIds.

2. Are the frontend client console logs saying that you're successfully getting connected to Ably?

If so, there is no reason why the messages wouldn't be sending. Perhaps it is worth checking if account wide you are sending the quantity of message you are expecting. If you find that you are sending them but you are not receiving them, that means that you are publishing to the wrong channels. The other way this could be going wrong is if you are using different API keys from different Ably apps for your development / production environment, and that your production keys do not have the capability to publish - but this should generate errors in the console.

3. Are your custom react-hooks working as intended?

I can't see anything wrong with your React hooks, and there is nothing wrong with writing your own, but I did want to point out that Ably has now released a new [library of react-hooks](https://ably.com/docs/spaces/react), and I would suggest looking at the sample app [linked here](https://github.com/ably/ably-js/tree/main/src/platform/react-hooks/sample-app/src) for some example use. That said, if your hooks worked in development there is no reason they would not work in the same way in production.

This allows you to subscribe to specific message names on a channel like this, and automatically handles mounting and unmounting.

```
const YourComponentContainingAblyReactHooks: () => {
    const [messages, updateMessages] = useState<Types.Message[]>([]);
    useChannel(
    { channelName: 'your-channel-name' }, (message) => {
        if (message.name == "MATCH_FOUND") {
       updateMessages((prev) => [...prev, message]);
           const match_found_data = message.data;
           // Do whatever you like with the data.
         } 
         if (message.name == "MATCH_NOT_FOUND") {
           const match_not_found_data = message.data;
           // Do whatever you like with the data.
         } 
    });
}
export default YourComponentContainingAblyReactHooks;
```

To get use of these react hooks, you have to open your Ably client in the the parent component, and pass your component containing Ably react-hooks inside an `<AblyProvider>` function:

```
import * as Ably from 'ably';
import { Types } from "ably";
import YourComponentContainingAblyReactHooks from "...";

export default function YourClient() {
      const [client, setClient] = useState<InstanceType<typeof Ably.Realtime.Promise> | null>(null);
      const [clientId, setClientId] = useState('');
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const newClient = new Ably.Realtime.Promise({
          authUrl: '/token',
          authMethod: 'POST',
          clientId: `<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>`
        });
    
        newClient.connection.once('connected', () => {
          setClientId(newClient.auth.clientId);
          console.log("Successful connection made with clientId = " + newClient.auth.clientId);
        });
    
        setClient(newClient);
    
        return () => {
          newClient.close();
        };
      }, []);
    
      return client ? (
        <AblyProvider client={client}>
          <YourComponentContainingAblyReactHooks />
        </AblyProvider>
      ) : (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that Vercel has a default execution timeout for their backend functions (serverless functions). That means that within 10 seconds or so, the ably connection would die out. This is why the backend subscriptions were not triggering.

My solution is to send a regular HTTP request to the backend instead of publishing. Then, on the backend, instead of publishing via ably realtime, I'll simply use the REST API (which does not require a persistent connection to Ably). This has worked fine for me. Hopefully this helps someone else.

The TLDR is - if your backend subscriptions aren't working in a Vercel production environment, this is probably the issue^.